# How to send a command with arguments without spaces in Windows

Tags: windows, cmd, command-line, terminal

Is there a way to execute a command with arguments in **Windows** without spaces?

```
echo 1 > a
```

Needs to be:

```
echo1>a
```

In [Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/351331/how-to-send-a-command-with-arguments-without-spaces) you can use `${IFS}` but I didn't find it to work in Windows:

```
echo${IFS}1${IFS}>a
```

Comment: Would you mind to tell us why do you need this?

Comment: I am creating a PoC for bug in some product. It is not enough to tell them about the bug, I need to show the risk. Their product preventing white spaces, I want to show them that it is not enough so they can add a different solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cmd
(echo(1)>a
```

or

```cmd
(echo/1)>a
```

can be done.

An alternative is

```cmd
>a=echo/1
```

because the `=`-sign is a [token separator](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html#delimiters) just like the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> (you may also use `,` or `;` instead).

But regard, that

```cmd
echo/1>a
```

can**not** be used, because `1>` is then taken as the [redirection operator](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html).

---

A completely different solution is to first assign a <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to a variable and then to use it:

```cmd
rem // This assigns a single space character:
set "SPC= "
rem // A space before `>` would also be echoed out, hence use parenthesis:
(echo%SPC%1)>%SPC%a
rem // Alternatively, rearrange the command line:
>%SPC%a%SPC%echo%SPC%1
```

This works, because immediate variable (`%`-)expansion happens before command token recognition.

Comment: Thank you for you explanation. It seems to do the work although I needed to mention in the question that I looked for something more global but I see that for example the use of `=` can work with `echo=1` and also with `dir=c:\` so for it good enough for me and also you other alternative looks good. thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Does this produce what you are seeking?

```
ECHO]1>a
```

Comment: Yes but I would be happier if it was something global because it won't work with `dir]c:\` but I suppose it was my mistake I didn't mention it in the question. But it in my case it is good enough, so thank you

Comment: Clearly, I did not understand the full scope of what you were trying to accomplish. This is not the answer.